# Typescript : error: unknown option '--compiler'

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

While running test with protractor (and typescript) ,
(i.e) npm test => protractor typeScript/config/config.js  we are getting error

**error: unknown option '--compiler'**

Our tsconfig.json contains below :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "commonjs",        
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "typeScript",
        "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ],
        "types": ["node","@cucumber/cucumber"], 
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true       
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typescript"
    ]
}
```

Also tried upgrading typescript, protractor to the latest, no luck.

Comment: this was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868645/when-i-try-to-run-protractor-test-with-cucumber-the-following-error-message-appe/66872157#66872157 however still not answered. I'd reach out to the user that posted this question first to see if he resolved it

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! removing compiler under CucumberOpts works... thought issue with ts compiler